# Facing problem in implementing Ajax by JQuery in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have designed some pages to show topics by Ajax through JQuery. All of these works fine in Mozilla Firefox but not at all working in Internet Explorer.
Whenever checked in error console of Internet Explorer, it shows the error something like this-

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 120
Char: 476
Code: 0
URI: http://kkkcodes.byethost33.com/css/jquery.min.js
```

Even you can check the below mentioned pages in Internet Explorer-here you can find a link **Older posts>>>** just click it to view the topics.

[Link Older posts>>> must be clicked to retrieve the topics](http://kkkcodes.byethost33.com/searchjava.php)

[Link Older posts>>> must be clicked to retrieve the topics](http://kkkcodes.byethost33.com/searchc.php)

[Link Older posts>>> must be clicked to retrieve the topics](http://kkkcodes.byethost33.com/freesoft.php)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, The probelm is  in XMLHttpRequest, try using the latest version of Jquery.

Edit:

Trying on IE7 and IE8 works fine